# how to break a large image into 8 equal parts in android

Tags: android

i just want to break a large image into some equal parts like 4, 6 or 8.
 can we do it?
 actually i want to store every parts of image as a separate image in my 
 drawable folder for future use.

can any one help me?

Thanks in advance
 sunit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into Bitmap definition

with [this][1] you should be able to do it

```
public static Bitmap createBitmap (Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height, Matrix m, boolean filter)
```

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap, int, int, int, int, android.graphics.Matrix, boolean)

edit:
maybe this one is simpler

> public static Bitmap createBitmap (Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)

should look something like this (divided in 4, you'll have to work out your loops to make it work on 4,6,8 ...

```
Bitmap source = ...;
int halfWidth = source.getWidth()/2;
int halfHeight = source.getHeight()/2; 
Bitmap topleft, topright, bottomleft, bottomright;
topleft = createBitmap(source,0,0,halfWidth ,halfHeight);
topright= createBitmap(source,halfWidth ,0,halfWidth ,halfHeight); 
bottomleft= createBitmap(source ,0,halfHeight,halfWidth ,halfHeight);
bottomright = createBitmap(source ,halfWidth ,halfHeight,halfWidth ,halfHeight);
```

I don't have time to create a test code on my computer put this should get you started.

Also try this

```
try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/image"+num+".png");
                mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

it will create a copy of the bitmap on your sdcard that will help you see if the bitmap is generated correctly.

Comment: I am not able to find any solution by using above code. can you please help me. how can i get it implemented.

Comment: if this works don't forget to leave a feedback here for others by marking it ^^

Comment: This solution only works if you can load the original large image in the first place. How can the same question be answered if the original image is very large? The only workaround I know is to downsample the image when loading it with a `BitmapFactory`, hence reducing the quality of the image.